# How to change file and directory name using c# regex

Tags: c#, regex, file-rename

I am new at C#. I want to write a programme for changing files' and directories' names.

```
public static string ToUrlSlug(this string text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(
        Regex.Replace(
            Regex.Replace(
                text.Trim().ToLower()
                           .Replace("ö", "o")
                           .Replace("ç", "c")
                           .Replace("ş", "s")
                           .Replace("ı", "i")
                           .Replace("ğ", "g")
                           .Replace("ü", "u"),
                                @"\s+", " "), //multiple spaces to one space
                            @"\s", "-"), //spaces to hypens
                        @"[^a-z0-9\s-]", ""); //removing invalid chars
}
```

I want to work on path `C:\Users\dell\Desktop\abc`.
How can I add this path to my programme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **many** special cases you should handle to encode a file name as URL, couldn't you use HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode()?
I'm not sure this is what you want anyway:

```
public void RenameFiles(string folderPath, string searchPattern = "*.*")
{
 foreach (string path in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, searchPattern))
 {
  string currentFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
  string newFileName = ToUrlSlug(currentFileName);

  if (!currentFileName.Equals(newFileName))
  {
   string newPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path),
    newFileName +  Path.GetExtension(path));

   File.Move(path, newPath);
  }
 }
}
```